# Issuer of the Assertion not found or multiple. A valid SubjectConfirmation was not found

Tags: saml

I am generating unsigned SAML response with signed assertion for my IDP. When I am validating it using samltool.com, it fails with following errors:

Issuer of the Assertion not found or multiple. 
A valid SubjectConfirmation was not found on this Response Found an invalid Signed Element. SAML Response rejected.

But when I generate Signed response with Unsigned assertion it passes without any error. I checked the overall XML is valid. I checked other posts but could find any answer.

Any thoughts around this issue, would help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_c2658c71-1361-48c6-b733-c95858146230" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-02-10T04:19:45.482Z" Destination="XXXXXXX" InResponseTo="samlrequest_25369109d2af475ebe51e0e94a95967a">
    <saml:Issuer>XXXXXXX</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <saml:Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ID="_3c6a8bfd-292a-473f-91b5-fac5352de06a" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2019-02-10T04:19:45.482Z">
        <saml:Issuer>XXXXXXX</saml:Issuer>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#_c2658c71-1361-48c6-b733-c95858146230">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>AYG+ZKBzsXPfpq94EcgFsvRgFLg=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX==</ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
        <saml:Subject>
            <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">XXXXX@XXXXXXXX.com</saml:NameID>
            <saml:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2019-02-10T04:24:45.482Z" Recipient="XXXXXXX" InResponseTo="samlrequest_25369109d2af475ebe51e0e94a95967a"/>
            </saml:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml:Subject>
        <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2019-02-10T04:19:45.482Z" NotOnOrAfter="2019-02-10T04:24:45.482Z">
            <saml:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml:Audience>XXXXXXX</saml:Audience>
            </saml:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml:Conditions>
        <saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2019-02-10T04:19:45.482Z" SessionNotOnOrAfter="2019-02-10T04:24:45.482Z" SessionIndex="9cb0eb45-3a0c-4fcf-90b7-3fab83a855ac">
            <saml:AuthnContext>
                <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml:AuthnContext>
        </saml:AuthnStatement>
        <saml:AttributeStatement>
            <saml:Attribute Name="Role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="Gender" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXXXXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="FirstName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>
            <saml:Attribute Name="LastName" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic">
                <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">XXXXXXX</saml:AttributeValue>
            </saml:Attribute>

        </saml:AttributeStatement>
    </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reference of your signature refers to the Response element whose id is _c2658c71-1361-48c6-b733-c95858146230 (search for ds:Reference URI="#_c2658c71-1361-48c6-b733-c95858146230"). You need to generate a signature for the Assertion element whose id is _3c6a8bfd-292a-473f-91b5-fac5352de06a.